# AutoFK index disabled during foreign key creation in pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, pgadmin-4

Trying to create a foreign key, but doesn't allow me to save the changes as it shows the error "Please specify covering index name." Cant specify the covering index unless i toggle the auto fk index switch. Which is disabled. I was able to create two other[image] foreign keys with no issue.

Comment: Welcome to the network :) Please provide the `create table` statements for all objects involved. Also see [repro] & [ask] for tips to help make you question easier to answer.

Comment: Why don't you ditch the GUI "builder" and run plain SQL statements instead? You should have SQL scripts to do that anyway (and they should be stored in a version control system like git or subversion)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name they save some typing an make production quickly. But when they misbehaves like this, they are no longer time and stroke savers but waste!